# TCP/IP Exhaustion Sending 2000 req/s

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-server-2012, tcp

I have an app that needs to send 2000 http get requests per second but when I do that, the client app cannot get response after a while. When I check tcp ip ports, i see lots of tcp ip ports that is TIME WAIT state.

So 2000 reqs per second is too much for one server ? Is there any best practice to run an application like that ?

I tried to change the server configuration but it did not help too much.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx

I am running code below while testing the scenario above,

```
    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:5000/")
    {
        Proxy = null
    };
    var counter = 0;
    while (true)
    {

        var request = new RestRequest("api/values", Method.GET) {Timeout = 5000};
        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode + "=> " + counter++);
        });

    }
```

Comment: that really depends on the server. is your program its only client? on the same local net? I'd say its near impossible on internet. what is an average response time per request? it would have to be well below 0.5ms per request to avoid contention if we assumed a single thread handling requests on server side. For human observers this is way faster than needed. why do you need such a high rate? btw. the loop in the code you posted has no fixed rate, it will fire as fast as it can with all cores of the CPU available to the scheduler.

Comment: This code looks like it might easily occupy all (theoretical) 65536 Tcp ports withing a few seconds. Server would have to respond very quickly to prevent that. Maybe check how many simultaeous requests you are actually having (i.e. increase a counter every time you begin a request, and decrease it every time a request ends).

Comment: You are sending AND receiving 2000 requests per second (given that you are calling localhost). Can your app respond to 2000 queries per second?

Comment: @dlatikay If you look at the `client` instantiation code, it's `localhost` that the OP is calling

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes it can respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with HTTP is it's really designed for 1 query and 1 response (yes I know there are ways to keep the socket open).

A better solution to your problem, is to open 1 standard TCP/IP socket to the server and send multiple queries (and get responses) down this single socket.

2000 queries per second isn't that many these days, so any decent server hardware would be able to keep up, provided your code is efficient.